# Azure DevOps Migrator Tool - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I have been using the latest version of the tool and I am receiving the below error. Previous versions of the tool would log me in or prompt me to do so but this one no longer seems to (if I'm in the right ballpark with the error message).

The user I run the tool as is a Project Collection Admin on the source and the target collections.

Can you help please?

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MigrationTools.TfsExtensions.ToProjectData(Project project) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\TfsExtensions.cs:line 125
   at MigrationTools.Clients.TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.GetProject() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\Clients\TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.cs:line 152
   at MigrationTools.Clients.TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.InnerConfigure(IMigrationClient migrationClient, Boolean bypassRules) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\Clients\TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.cs:line 261
   at MigrationTools.Clients.TfsMigrationClient.Configure(IMigrationClientConfig config, NetworkCredential credentials) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\Clients\TfsMigrationClient.cs:line 77
   at MigrationTools.MigrationEngine.GetTarget() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\MigrationEngine.cs:line 166
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.TeamMigrationContext.InternalExecute() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\TeamMigrationContext.cs:line 39
   at MigrationTools.Engine.Processors.MigrationProcessorBase.Execute() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\Engine\Processors\MigrationProcessorBase.cs:line 45
```

Comment: Looks to me like a configuration error instead. But it's hard to tell exactly what's wrong here without more details. Have you tried getting the project from the github repo and attaching a debugger, that would probably give much more insights in what's going on. The advantages of open source and all: https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools

Comment: I've regenerated the configuration.json file and pared it back to it's simplest form, added my target and source collection/projects and still I am getting the same error

Comment: From the error my guess would be that one of those project/collection name is misspelled or maybe in the wrong capitalization.

Comment: Or indeed that your user doesn't have access to it. You mention you are collection admin, but those don't always have permission to access all projects.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you have a valid Project name and appropriate access to Azure DevOps that the Migration Tools are rejecting the project based on unusual characters in the name. The most common one is a Space.

We shipped a fix in the latest version to allow Projects with spaces in the name.